# Android Studio - Creating a Loading/Splash Screen for WebView

Tags: android-studio, splash-screen

I have followed through this tutorial (I am completely new to Android Studio): [Loading/Splash Screen Tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-splash-screen-for-webview-in-android-studio-ef68ec05720a)

and I am unsure why my code isn't working correctly.

I get the loading circle come up on the app I have created, but it does not go away when the app loads the webpage.

I have gone over my code a few times now and I cannot see any errors (obviously there are some somewhere!) Just seems as if it isn't recognising that my webpage has loaded within the app.

Here is my code from my MainActivity.java file:

```
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
private WebView myWebView;
private ProgressBar spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setMinimumLogicalFontSize(1);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://node-red-test.ftp21.net:1024/ui");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { @Override public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){ handler.proceed(); } });
}

// This allows for a splash screen
// (and hide elements once the page loads)
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView myWebView, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // only make it invisible the FIRST time the app is run
        if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
            myWebView.setVisibility(myWebView.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        view.setVisibility(myWebView.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

I am currently running Android Studio version 2.1.2 - due to problems with later versions that I came across when following another tutorial.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you calling setWebViewClient() twice? The second call replaces the first custom client.

Comment: Hi Miles, Thanks for pointing that out! I followed a different tutorial for how to accept SSL certificates automatically, that is why that one was there. I just combined the code for the accepting SSL certificates into the first WebViewClient, and now it is running fine :) Thanks!

Comment: Hey @LiamBroughton , why don't you write the solution that worked for you and mark it as the answer, so people can easily find the solution if they are going through a similar issue? :P